# ASP .NET MVC4 Adding new items to view and model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I create a website for my wife. She's a teacher and she would like to have a possibility to create exercises for their students. The case is that she would like to create for instance the following exercise:

> Exercise 1: Fill the sentence using a correct word:
>
> 1. My wife is 30 ............. old
> 2. I live in this city for 30 .........

I have the following model:

```
public class Exercise
       {
           [Key]
           public Guid Id { get; set; }

           public string Name { get; set; }

           public string Description { get; set; }

           public ExerciseType Type { get; set; }

           public DifficulityLevel DifficulityLevel { get; set; }

           public List<ExerciseItem> Items { get; set; }

           public DateTime TimeOfCreation { get; set; }

           public DateTime TimeOfModification { get; set; }

       }

public class ExerciseItem
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public List<ExerciseItemOption> Options { get; set; }

        public ExerciseItemOption CorrectSelection { get; set; }

    }
```

I creates a View for my Exercise. I can fill in the basic properties like Name, Description, Difficulity Level and Type. Then I would like to create a button "Add exercise item". When clicked, a partial view (or something else) should be added dynamically where new ExerciseItem can be provided.
I've tried to following:
I've added a button

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add exercise item", 
                        "AddExerciseItem",
                        "Exercise", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod="GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, UpdateTargetId="ExerciseItems"})
```

and the appropriate div:

```
<div id="ExerciseItems"></div>
```

My action method looks as follows:

```
public ActionResult AddExerciseItem()
        {
            return PartialView("ExerciseItem", new ExerciseItem());
        }
```

and the partial view:

```
@model ElangWeb.Models.ExerciseItem
<fieldset>
    <legend>ExerciseItem</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, new { style = "width:200px" })
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

It works fine. However when I click button for creating a whole exercise, I do not have ExerciseItem collection in my model:

```
public ActionResult Create(Exercise exercise)
        {
            using (PersistanceManager pm = new PersistanceManager())
            {
                exercise.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                exercise.TimeOfCreation = DateTime.Now;
                exercise.TimeOfModification = DateTime.Now;
                pm.ExcerciseRepository.Add(exercise);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

How should I change the code in order to bind my list of added ExerciseItem objects to my model Exercise?

Comment: why do you use the partial to create your editorfor? is it because you have a dynamic number of exercises?

Comment: yes, that's right, I would like to have a dynamic number of exercise items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) about model binding. You basically need to create special names for the exercise items so that they get bound correctly.

e.g. partial:

```
@model ElangWeb.Models.ExerciseItem
<fieldset>
    <legend>ExerciseItem</legend>
    <label>content</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="ExcersiseItem.Index" value="SomeUniqueValueForThisItem" />
    <input type="text" name="ExcersiseItem[SomeUniqueValueForThisItem].Name" value="@Model.Content" />
</fieldset>
```

You can also look at my answer to this question [MVC3 Non-Sequential Indices and DefaultModelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598214/mvc3-non-sequential-indices-and-defaultmodelbinder). Thanks Yarx for finding it, I was actually trying to find it :)

Comment: Is this still the way to do it in MVC4?