# ASP.NET MVC5 Model Binder - Null when binding collection of collections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, defaultmodelbinder

I have researched all over the net but hopefully here someone can help me.

I have following ViewModel classes:

```
public class PersonEditViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public List<DictionaryRootViewModel> Interests { get; set; }
}

public class DictionaryRootViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DictionaryItemViewModel> Items;

    public DictionaryRootViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<DictionaryItemViewModel>();
    }
}

public class DictionaryItemViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

In the Edit view I use custom EditorTemplate to layout collection of Interests using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Interests)`. There are two EditorTemplates that do the rendering:

1. DictionaryRootViewModel.cshtml:

   ```
   @model Platforma.Models.DictionaryRootViewModel
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items)
   ```
2. DictionaryItemViewModel.cshtml:

   ```
   @model Platforma.Models.DictionaryItemViewModel
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Selected)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
   ```

**The problem:**

When submitting the form using POST, only the `Interests` collection gets populated and the `Interest.Items` collection is always empty.
The request contains (among others) following field names, they are also present when inspecting Request.Forms data in the controller action method.

- Interests[0].Id
- Interests[0].Name
- Interests[0].Items[0].Id
- Interests[0].Items[0].Selected

All contain proper values - but on the controller side, the object pvm in method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(PersonEditViewModel pvm)
{
}
```

contains data in Interests collection (items with correct id and name), but for each element of the collection its' subcollection of Items is empty.

How do I make it to correctly pick the model?

Comment: Not very familiar with mvc, but maybe your models must be [Serializable]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual - the answer was in front of me the whole time.
The DefaultModelBinder didn't pick up the Items values passed in request, because I "forgot" to mark Items collection as property - it was a field!
The correct form taking into account helpful remark by @pjobs:

`public List<DictionaryItemViewModel> Items`**{get;set;}**

Comment: :), I thought thats just shorthand , should have pointed it out

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time issue is with index, when you have collections posting, you either needs to have sequential index or have Interests[i].Items.Index hidden field if indexes are not sequential.

[Here is similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598214/mvc3-non-sequential-indices-and-defaultmodelbinder)

It will **not** work if you have

```
Interests[0].Id
Interests[0].Name
Interests[0].Items[0].Id
Interests[0].Items[0].Selected
Interests[0].Items[2].Id
Interests[0].Items[2].Selected
```

So to fix it you either make sure have sequencial indexes as

```
Interests[0].Id
Interests[0].Name
Interests[0].Items[0].Id
Interests[0].Items[0].Selected
Interests[0].Items[1].Id
Interests[0].Items[1].Selected
```

**OR**

```
Interests[0].Id
Interests[0].Name
Interests[0].Items.Index = 0 (hidden field)
Interests[0].Items[0].Id
Interests[0].Items[0].Selected
Interests[0].Items.Index = 2 (hidden field)
Interests[0].Items[2].Id
Interests[0].Items[2].Selected
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help! Unfortunately it does not seem to work. The first approach was already implemented, since I'm using built-in templating features of ASP.NET MVC5. I tried the other one and the results were the same.

Comment: can we see more info from your postback , I mean all things of your Request.Forms data

Comment: Another thing is can you change public ICollection<DictionaryItemViewModel> Items to public List<DictionaryItemViewModel> Items in your ViewModel and try

Comment: Hi, the change to List from ICollection doesn't help. All the fields from the request are here: http://pastebin.com/RgaKQEre  . You can see a few more collections of collections - all of them fail in the same way as Interests collection.

Comment: wow thats lots of collection of collections, you got these from Posted Form...? very big form